# InvalidCastException when creating a mailbox enabled user in active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server

I have a C# (Visual Studio 2010) application to manage objects in Microsoft Active Directory. If I want to create a mailbox enabled user I get an InvalidCastException at this point:

```
IMailboxStore mailbox = (IMailboxStore)NewUser.NativeObject;
```

Here's my full code:

```
public void CreateUser(string Path,
                       string sAdminUserName,
                       string sAdminUserPassword,
                       string LastName,
                       string FirstName,
                       string sUserName,
                       string sUserPassword,
                       string sHomeMDB)
{
    DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(Path, sAdminUserName, sAdminUserPassword);
    DirectoryEntry NewUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + LastName + "." + FirstName, "user");

    NewUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = sUserName;

    NewUser.CommitChanges();
    NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { sUserPassword});
    NewUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x200;
    NewUser.CommitChanges();

    try
    {
        IMailboxStore mailbox = (IMailboxStore)NewUser;
        mailbox.CreateMailbox(sHomeMDB);
        NewUser.CommitChanges();
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm developing on a client which is not the exchange server. That's why I have installed the Exchange Management Tools. But unfortunately this error still happens.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code was calling `(IMailboxStore)NewUser` instead of `(IMailboxStore)NewUser.NativeObject`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've also tried your version but I get the same error.

Comment: How did you get your interop?  Did you install "Exchange Management
Components" on the machine that you are running the code?

Comment: Hm I've installed the [Exchange System Manager.](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17836) Did you mean that?

Comment: I am not very sure.  It looks like to me you don't have that COM interface registered in your machine at all.  How did you get the interop?  Did you download it somewhere or did you generate it from tlbimp?

Comment: I've downloaded the Exchange System Manager. Then I added an assembly in Visual Studio (Add assembly -> COM -> Microsoft CDO for Exchange Management Library). I've also tried to refer directly to the cdoexm.dll in C:\Program Files(x86)\Exchsrvr\bin but that gieves me the same error.

Comment: I tried again some things to solve the problem. I've tried to use tlbimp.exe to build a .Net wrapper for the cdoexm.dll I'm using. You can find some details here [link](http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/2010/05/create-an-exchange-2003-mailbox-with-powershell-and-cdoexm/). Unfortunately this gives me another error: `TlbImp : error TI1033 : Cannot find type 'ADODB.Fields_Deprecated' in 'ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. There could be a mismatch between the referenced assembly and the type library.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this question is very old, I'd like to post a solution for my problem which I found out a while ago. Maybe this can help other people with the same problem.

In the project properties -> Configuration Manager -> Active Solution Platform I chose 64-bit platform. That's why the problem occured. The IMailboxStore interface just didn't exist for 64-bit. So I've changed the setting back to 32-bit and the error was gone.